# update_attributes() not working for nested attributes and paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, nested-attributes, update-attributes

My model describes paragraphs and images, where each paragraph has_many images. For the image handling, I use paperclip. For mass assignment, I use the images as nested_attributes of a paragraph. The relevant code:

model/paragraph.rb

```
class Paragraph < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, :dependent => :destroy
  attr_accessible :text, :images_attributes, :images
  attr_accessor :text
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['photo'].blank? }
end
```

model/image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :paragraph
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :original => '250*250>' }
  attr_accessible :caption, :photo
  attr_accessor :caption
end
```

paragraph.text and image.caption are temporary attributes (not in the database). If I update a paragraph in the controller or the rails console (assuming that image with id=1 really belongs to the first paragraph), the following updates paragraph.text as expected, but does not update image.caption at all:

```
Paragraph.first.update_attributes({"text" => "foo", "images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"caption"=>"bar", "id"=>"1"}}})
```

But in similar setups (nested temporary attributes) without using paperclip, it works as expected, e.g. for pages, where a page has_many paragraphs:

```
Page.first.update_attributes({"paragraphs_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"text"=>"test", "id"=>"1"}}})
```

This updates the values of the page and the nested paragraphs with their temporary text attribute as expected, which makes me guessing, that it might be a paperclip issue...

Any help appreciated! Thanks!!!

Comment: I personally would move the updating of the `Paragraph` data object to `Paragraph` as I am not the greatest fan of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. So `Page.first.paragraph.update(caption: 'bar', id: 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Given `images_attributes` of

```
{"0"=>{"caption"=>"bar", "id"=>"1"}}
```

I believe the lack of a `photo` key is causing it to be rejected by `Paragraph` due to the `reject_if` option of the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` call. `attributes['photo']` will be `nil` when not provided and `nil.blank?` is `true`, so it's rejected.